# How to Initialize a Private Multidimensional Array

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, initialization, private

How would I initialize a private array where that one hundred items each equal a two-item array such as `{-1, 0}`. My code below obviously does not work since I am asking you all.

example.h:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE
#define EXAMPLE

class Example {
private:
    char grid[10][10];
public:
    Example();
};

#endif
```

example.cpp:

```
#include "example.h"
#include <iostream>

Example::Example() : grid({-1, 0}) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently possible with C++. In C++0x it will be possible with braces, like

```
Example::Example() : grid{{-1, 0}} {}
```

And for the time being, you can wrap that array in a class, without any performance loss (the array will still be a normal, native multidimensional array)

```
class Example {
private:
    struct data {
      char grid[10][10];
      static data newData() {
        data d = {{
          { -1, 0 }, { -2, 1 } /* ... */
        }};
        return d;
      }
    } d;

public:
    Example() : d(data::newData()) { }
};
```

Comment: Hmm. What if I were willing to make a compromise and initialize say `grid[10][10][2]` where that all 200 items were 0?

Comment: @Tyler then you can just say `Example() : grid() {}`. This works fine.

Comment: Hmm, I found a pretty relevant link to what you first said in the answer: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't initialise members like this. You have to manually assign to each value in the constructor body using `std::fill` (or good old `=` and a loop).

This will change in C++0x, though, in which you can write code like the code you posted.

<sub>(Also, you have a mismatch in your question. You declare an array of 10 arrays of 10 chars each, but your initialisation attempt bears no resemblance to that use case whatsoever. It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do, but since you'll have to use a different approach anyway I suppose it doesn't really matter for this answer.)</sub>

Comment: How is it not clear? Did you just skip straight to the code? I want one-hundred arrays like `{-1, 0}`. The 10x10 grid is necessary over just an array of 100 because this is a two-dimensional grid.

Comment: @Tyler: No, I read the question. It's not clear what you're trying to do because the code attempt says something completely different to the text. Your initialisation attempt is for a two-element, 1D array, not a 10x10 2D array.

Comment: I also mentioned I knew the code was incorrect. I thought the code example might build onto what I was saying but I guess it didn't go as planned. :/

Comment: @Tyler: No worries; we know what you meant now. My answer stands.